# How to get a checkmark before selected item in DropDown ipywidget

Tags: python, dropdown, selecteditem

I am a begineer in python and ipywidgets.

I am trying to get a checkmark before slected item in ipywidget[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpQqC.png)

```
drop_down_x = 
widgets.Dropdown(options=['All','Natural','Lab'],
value='All',
description='Origin',
icon='check',
DescriptionStyle='CheckBoxStyleModel',
disabled=False)
```

Please help

I tried several things but could not get it.

Comment: [You should post code instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)